# How to declare and use a local component as module?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, module, node-modules

I `export const FontXLarge = 18;` in ThemeFont.ts.
When I want to use it, I used to use `import {FontXLarge} from '../theme/ThemeFont';`

After I add

```
{
    "name": "theme"
}
```

I can use `import {FontXLarge} from 'theme/ThemeFont';` but I can't link to the folder.

So I think that if I declare module 'ThemeFont' I can link it. And the fact that I did it. When I ctrl + click (or alt + click in VSCode, depending on your setting), it can open the file  **ThemeFont.ts** when I use `import {FontXLarge} from 'ThemeFont';`

```
declare module 'ThemeFont' {
  export const FontXLarge = 18;
}
```

When hover, it will show like that

[image]

**But** it shows **error** when build: Unable to resolve module ThemeFont in node_modules

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use this library to declare local component https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver

My config for it:

- create/edit: **tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./app",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "outDir": "../dst/",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "lib": ["es2016"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

- create/edit **jsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./app/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- create/edit **jsconfig.js**

```js
System.config({
  paths: {
    '@/*': './app/*',
  },
})
```

- edit **babel.config.js**

```js
const presets = ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'];
const plugins = [
  [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    // {
    //   globals: ['__scanQRCodes', '__decode'],
    // },
  ],
  [
    'module-resolver',
    {
      root: ['./app'],
      extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
      alias: {
        '@': './app',
      },
    },
  ],
];
const env = {
  production: {
    plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel'],
  },
};

module.exports = {
  presets,
  plugins,
  env,
};
```

Now you can use

```
import {FontXLarge} from '@/Theme/ThemeFont';
```

remember that after config it, resetting app cache:

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```